# If $A \subseteq I_m$ such that $m \in A$, and if $n \in A \Rightarrow n+1 \in A$, then $A=I_m$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that:

> If $A \subseteq I_m$ such that $m \in A$, and if $n \in A \Rightarrow n+1 \in A$, then $A=I_m$. ($I_m$ is a sequence).

I've written my proof as following, but I'm not sure it's totally correct or if it's missing something:

For $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $m\in A$, lets assume that if $n\in A$ then $n+1 \in A$.

Also, since $A \subseteq I_m$, then $m,n,n+1 \in I_m$.

Now, we want to proof that $I_m \subseteq A$. We can define that $\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$, $I_m \subseteq \mathbb{Z}:=\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:n\geq m\}$, and since it's clear that $n<n+1$, then $m\leq n<n+1$. By hypothesis, we know that $m\in A$, and that if $n\in A \Rightarrow n+1\in A$. Since $m,n,n+1 \in I_m$ and $m,n,n+1 \in A$, it's clear that $I_m \subseteq A$.

Hence, since $A \subseteq I_m\quad \wedge \quad  I_m \subseteq A \Rightarrow I_m=A$, then we have proved that if $A \subseteq I_m$ such that $m \in A$, and if $n \in A \Rightarrow n+1 \in A$, then $A=I_m$.

Comment: Context? What is $I_m$ ?

Comment: $I_m$ is a sequence, the exercise doesn't say anything else about it. The reason I said that we could define that $\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$, $I_m \subseteq \mathbb{Z}:=\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:n\geq m\}$ is because that's the definition I have in my textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I_m \neq A$, let $m_0 = \min(I_m\setminus A)$ (any *non-empty* subset of $\Bbb Z$ with a lower bound has a minimum).
Then $m \neq m_0$ (as $m \in A$ is given) and it follows that $m_0 -1 \in I_m$ as well (by definition of $I_m$) but it has to be in $A$ by minimality of $m_0$ but then $m_0 = (m_0 -1) +1 \in A$ by the assumption on $A$ and we have a contradiction.

Comment: When you said that $m_0 -1$ has to be in A by minimality of $m_0$, could you explain to me what does this mean?